# Flatten Complex Object To Multiple Flatten Objects Using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a View Model such as

```
public class RootViewModel
{
    public CreateCompanyViewModel Company { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    public CreateUserTypeViewModel UserType { get; set; }
}
```

And `CreateCompanyViewModel` and `CreateUserTypeViewModel` are like

```
public class CreateCompanyViewModel
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}

public class CreateUserTypeViewModel
{
    public string UserTypeName { get; set; }
}
```

I want this RootVM to be flattened to multiple DTO's. The 3 DTO's for the above RootVM I have are like

```
public class UserDTO
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}

public class CompanyDTO
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}

public class UserTypeDTO
{
    public string UserTypeName { get; set; }
}
```

**NOTE :** Note that `CompanyDTO` and `UserTypeDTO` are not nested object (part of) `UserDTO` unlike RootVM.

When I'm doing the mapping using AutoMapper RootVM properties gets mapped to `UserDTO` but `CompanyDTO` and `UserTypeDTO` are null as expected.

I tried mapping them by using `ForMember` function with `MapFrom` and `ResolveUsing` methods, but both of them shows error as

> Custom configuration for members is only supported for top-level
>   individual members on a type.

**UPDATE**
Below is my mapping code

```
CreateMap<RootViewModel, CompanyDTO>();
CreateMap<RootViewModel, UserDTO>();
CreateMap<RootViewModel, UserTypeDTO>();
CreateMap<CreateCompanyViewModel, CompanyDTO>();
CreateMap<CreateUserTypeViewModel, UserTypeDTO>();
```

I'm using **AutoMapper 5.2.0**

**UPDATE - Fix :**
Well what I found is, either I have to use .ForMember for all the properties manually, else for automatic convention to work, I need to use https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Flattening or https://arnabroychowdhurypersonal.wordpress.com/2014/03/08/flattening-object-with-automapper/.

This is the only way to make it work.

Wish I could do `.ForMember(d => d, s => s.MapFrom(x => x.Company))` and it'd map all the properties from `CreateCompanyViewModel => CompanyDTO`. This would have been very handy, but AutoMapper doesn't supports this.

Comment: have you added mapping for company CompanyDTO and CreateCompanyViewModel separately ?

Comment: I have added mapping for RootViewModel => UserDTO, RootViewModel => CompanyDTO, RootViewModel => UserTypeDTO, CreateCompanyViewModel  => CompanyDTO, CreateUserTypeViewModel => UserTypeDTO

Comment: remove RootViewModel => CompanyDTO and  RootViewModel => UserTypeDTO and try

Comment: No it doesn't works as I'm trying to get a CompanyDTO from RootViewModel and removing the mapping throws error as No Mapping Configuration Exists from RootViewModel => CompanyDTO

Comment: Well can you post your mapping code ?

Comment: And what about actual resolving code  where it throws error ?

Comment: Well it's like `CreateCompanyDTO companyDTO = Mapper.Map<RootViewModel, CreateCompanyDTO>(model);`

Comment: I think first I need to transform RootViewModel to CreateCompanyViewModel  and then CreateCompanyViewModel  to CompanyDTO. Is it like that?

Comment: you need to provide formember mapping for property like CompanyName and UserTypeName

Answer (score 2):

Try following

```
        CreateMap<CreateCompanyViewModel, CompanyDTO>();
        CreateMap<CreateUserTypeViewModel, UserTypeDTO>();

        CreateMap<RootViewModel, CompanyDTO>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.CompanyName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Company.CompanyName));

        CreateMap < RootViewModel, UserTypeDTO()
              .ForMember(dest => dest.UserTypeName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.UserType.UserTypeName));

        CreateMap<RootViewModel, UserDTO>();
```

Comment: It's working this way, but I have to now write around 30 properties manually. I was looking for some conventional way (automatic). I think I have found one but it won't apply to my case. https://arnabroychowdhurypersonal.wordpress.com/2014/03/08/flattening-object-with-automapper/